# SESSION problem when using GET method in php

Tags: php, session, get

> ```
> <?php session_start();?>
>
> <a href="abc.php?color=red"> send the color </a>
> <br><br>
> <?php
> @$_SESSION['color'] = $_GET['color'];
> echo $_SESSION['color'];
> ?>
>
> <br>
> <br>
> <a href="abc.php"> check the session variable </a>
> ```

hi,
i need help for the above code.

i want to pass a variable to session.

with above code im doing this but the session variable dissappears when i refresh the page or when i click the bottom link. i want the  `echo $_SESSION['color'];` sticky

what should i do?
with regards

Comment: The computer will run your program exactly as written, so make sure you write what you intend.

Comment: Just to note: Do not use the @ error suppression operator unless there is absolutely, positively no alternative. Don't use it just because a warning or notice is a bit annoying.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning value of $_GET['color'] no matter if there is such GET variable or not. Because of this, when there is no $_GET['color'] you are loosing the session variable.
it have to be:

```
if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
    $_SESSION['color'] = $_GET['color'];
}
echo isset($_SESSION['color']) ? $_SESSION['color'] : '';
```

Comment: echo isset($_SESSION['color']) ? $_SESSION['color']'';                what does this line do?  ? : these operators? thx

Comment: It is called [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and it is short version of `if (isset($_SESSION['color'])) {echo $_SESSION['color'];} else {echo '';}`

Answer (score 1):

When `$_GET['color']` is empty because `color` is not in the query string of the URL, you still assign that empty value to `$_SESSION['color']`.

Don't do that and the value you set won't be overwritten. Nothing was disappearing on its own.